# Angularjs select elements from list and display in textarea

Tags: arrays, angularjs, textarea

I have a problem with Angular and nya-select.

Example array in my angular controller:

```
vm.arrayCollection = [
  { name: 'Alice',      mail: 'Class A' },
  { name: 'Bob', mail: 'Class B1' },
  { name: 'Carl', mail: 'Class A2' },
  { name: 'Daniel', mail: 'Class B2' },
  { name: 'Emi', mail: 'Class A3' },
  { name: 'Flank', mail: 'Class B3' },
  { name: 'George', mail: 'Class C4' },
  { name: 'Harry', mail: 'Class C5' }
];
```

I have select option element:

```
<ol class = "nya-bs-select" ng-model = "myModel">
  <li nya-bs-option="person in myController.arrayCollection">
    <a>
      {{ person.name }}
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

And second one is "textarea" :

```
  <textarea ng-model="myModel2">
    ... ?
  </textarea >
```

I would like to achieve this :

When I change "myModel" by choosing another person name from the first select option -> I want to set appropiate "mail" in the textarea.

Ex. when I choose "Alice" -> I would like to display "Class A" in the textarea. Moreover, when I multiselect "Alice", "Bob" -> I would like to display "Class A, Class B1"

Could you be so kind and help me How to achieve this ? (Multiselect is done by "nya-select" plugin -> so this is ok. I do not know how to display "mail" value from arrayCollection on the basis of name...

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the plugin you are using, however, I have tried to achieve what you wanted using multiple attribute of select element.

```
<select multiple="multiple" ng-model="selectedValues">
      <option ng-repeat="mail in a" value="{{mail.name}}">{{mail.mail}}</option>

    </select>
    <textarea>{{selectedValues}}</textarea>
```

Please review the plunker at "http://plnkr.co/edit/u2sXnMkYSEYshAcLgyn7?p=preview"

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works perfectly when we have "usual" select, but in my "select" which comes from nya-bootstrap-select, it does not use <option> values, but <ol> and <li> values -> When I insert <li value={{...}}> -> items will not show... and I do not know how to resolve this

Comment: Thank you for the update. Sorry being unfamiliar with the nya-bootstrap-select, will not be able to help.

Comment: :( I regret that you are not able to help me... But thank you for great response.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine. Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe the solution above, with <span>...</span> should work somehow... but I do know how to achieve this, because it only displays this text : <span ng-repeat> instead of work... Maybe you can advise me what should I do ?

Comment: It is because textarea does not understand tags. Anything inside textarea is plain string. You can not use any html tag inside textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Answer updated as per the comments below. OP is asking for a generic element to be reused on the page. There are possibly other/easier ways to do this, but I am extending the previous answer.

Set `value` attribute in each list element to `person` (this is needed for regular multi-select list, although may not be needed for nya-select):

```
<li nya-bs-option="person in myController.arrayCollection" value="{{person}}">
```

The ng-model `myModel` in the ordered list should contain the selections. We'll use that to render the content in the textarea. Add the following directive to the application:

```
myApp.directive('txtArea', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'true',
        scope: {data: '=', property: '@'},
        template: "<textarea readonly>{{result()}}</textarea>",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.result = function() {
                var ret = "";
                angular.forEach(scope.data, function(value, key) {
                    var suff = (key === scope.data.length - 1) ? '' : ', ';
                    ret += JSON.parse(value)[scope.property] + suff;
                });
                return ret;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

The directive is generic and can be reused across controllers. This also adds a comma after each intermediary value. Now replace the `textarea` element with:

```
<txt-area data="myModel" property="mail"></txt-area>
```

`myModel` is the model bound to the ordered list and `mail` is the property to use in the directive/filter.

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uaqbj7p8/5/) with regular multi-select list.

Latest updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uaqbj7p8/8/) based on discussion below.

Comment: Thank you for quick response, but unfortunately your solution does not work, because this text <span ...> is displayed as "static text", it does not work as angular ng-repeat.

Comment: Could you help me with this ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It's a bit late, so I apologise for that :-) Check my updated answer. Unless you put together some jsfiddle though we can't test it. It works on normal select.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! It works perfectly, but... I have a few questions and concerns...This directive works fine, but it is strictly connected with this angular model... what if I have 10 or more textareas on the website ? then I have to have 10 and more directives -> and I think this is wrong... moreover I wanted to add placeholder to this textarea -> and it does not work... If you have a free time please advise me what should I achieve my goals...

Comment: Moreover -> When I add value="{{person.mail}}" to <li...> -> Elements do not appear on the list... -> I have to remove this and add "value.mail" to this directive... -> Then works, but it is stricly coupled with my model...

Comment: I suspect textarea is not the element you want to use in your scenario. Regardless though, what you are asking can be done by isolating the scope of the directive and adding attrs to the element (txt-area). Check out the updated jffiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uaqbj7p8/5 The directive is now generic and can be parameterised with the data and property (e.g. mail) you want to use via attrs in the txt-area element. You can reuse it across controllers.

Comment: Thank you Chris ! It works ! -> Only one thing which I've changed is : value[scope.property] -> then it works... but I have another problem with placeholder, because it does not display...

Comment: No problem. If I understand your question correctly, you want to add a placeholder attr to textarea? You can add whatever attrs to txt-area and those will magrate over to the new element (textarea). See updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uaqbj7p8/8/ You can do the same with the 'property' attr since it is not binding to a scope variable, and then use it in the link function as 'attrs.property' rather than 'scope.property'. See updated jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank your Chris ! It works nicely, but only if textarea is in "readonly" -> when I remove this, and I would like to add possibility to change textarea (not only read parameters from the list) -> Place holder dissapears and select element from the list is not working anymore... Maybe you have solution for this ?

Comment: Moreover -> I would like to achieve this functionality : not only fill textarea on the basis of choosen elements from the list, but add additional text inserted by user -> when user decides that wants to add element from the list (some data is written in textarea) -> select element from the list and is "appended" to existing text instead of "clear" all textarea and insert values from the list

Comment: This is a different problem from what you originaly asked. Like i said, based on your original question, it did not seem that textarea was the appropriate element. You were looking for more like a label to display selected values from the list (this is what you ask in the question). What you are asking now can be done, but it's a different problem. Perhaps start a new question and we can take our discussion there :-)

Comment: Thanks Chris, I created the new one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695647/angularjs-select-elements-into-textarea-and-own-text

Comment: I would like to add also ng-model to my txtArea directive -> For future read elements from this directive, but when I add ng-model like this : <txt-area data="myModel" property="mail" ng-model="modelTextArea"></txt-area> -> this does not work and my elements which are selected via select option -> does not display in this textArea... How should I do this ?

Comment: See my answer in your new thread. Please mark this as correct if you feel it meets the requirements of your initial question.

Comment: Dear Chris, I am not able to find it, where is it ? I could not find it on website : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695647/angularjs-select-elements-into-textarea-and-own-text

Comment: Thank you, now I can see this post :)