# Append selected list elements into textarea, add own text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, textarea

On the basis of this post : [Angularjs select elements from list and display in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686804/angularjs-select-elements-from-list-and-display-in-textarea)

I would like to add functionality :

1. Fill textarea on the basis of chosen elements from the list.
2. Add additional text inserted by user -> when user decides that he/she wants to add element from the list (some data is written in textarea), select element from the list and "append" to existing text instead of "clear" all textarea and insert values from the list

Could you be so kind and explain me how should I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uaqbj7p8/12/) doing what you ask. Every time you click on a list element it is appended to the textarea.

The main function is a generic directive that you can reuse across controllers:

```
myApp.directive('txtArea', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: 'true',
        scope: {data: '=', model: '=ngModel'},
        template: "<textarea></textarea>",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal) {
                    scope.model += JSON.parse(newVal[0])[attrs.property];
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

To use the directive, insert the following in your HTML (at the proper location - see jsfiddle):

```
<txt-area data="myModel" property="mail" placeholder="expected value" ng-model='model' ng-trim='false'></txt-area>
```

- data `myModel` is the selection data from the select list, as [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30687179/2509908).
- property `mail` is the property to use for extracting values from selected element.
- `model` holds the textarea's content, which you can reuse as you like in your app.

Here's the complete relevant HTML code:

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="Main">            
        <p>Original</p>
        <select multiple="multiple" ng-model="myModel">
          <option ng-repeat="d in data" value="{{d}}">{{d.mail}}</option>
        </select>

        <txt-area data="myModel" property="mail" placeholder="expected value" ng-model='model' ng-trim='false'></txt-area>

        <div>{{model}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the controller and app sections:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Main', function($scope){
    $scope.data = [{mail:"a@foo"},{mail:"b@foo"},{mail:"c@foo"}];
    $scope.model = "";
});
```

Make sure that you define/initialise each directive's model (e.g. `$scope.model = ""`) as above, otherwise it will appear as initially undefined.

Comment: Dear Chris, Thank you very much ! It works like a charm !!! I adjusted my approach on the basis of yours guidance and it works ! Thank you once again. Actually I am starting my work with angularjs and I am not familiar with it yet like you. Maybe you can advise me a good tutorial which can lead me step by step into deep angular world ?

Comment: Glad I could help :-) A few introductory links to get you started: [1](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/how-to-learn-angular.html), [2](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/index.html), [3](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/). We used directives in our discussion, so have a go at [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/) as well. The [Mean Machine](https://leanpub.com/mean-machine) is a fairly decent beginner's book on the MEAN stack (MongoDB, Express, Angular, Node).

Comment: There are a few quite decent books out there on Angular and single page apps. Your best resource though is the [Angular site](https://angularjs.org/) itself, which has tutorials and descriptive API references. The current site is also second to none. Have fun exploring!